# Calculating equilibrium point of non-linear ODE with free parameter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I have two ordinary differential equations equations:

$$
\dot{x}=1+x^{2}y-(1+A)x
$$

$$
\dot{y}=Ax-yx^{2}
$$

I need to find the single equilibrium point in terms of $A$. So set $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ to zero.

I have rearranged Equation 2 to $Ax=yx^{2}$ and then substituted this into Equation 1. This allows me to solve for $x$, giving $x=1$.

I then solve for $y$ and get the point $(1,A)$.

Is this the correct method?

Comment: Is $A$ just a variable?

Answer (score 5):

We have:

$$
\dot{x}=1+x^{2}y-(1+A)x
$$

$$
\dot{y}=Ax-yx^{2}
$$

So, to find the equilibrium points, we need to simultaneously find $x' = y' = 0$.

We have:

$\dot{x}=1+x^{2}y-(1+A)x = 0$ and $\dot{y}=Ax-yx^{2} = 0$.

From the second equation, we get that $x^2 y = Ax$ and substitute that back in to the first equation, yielding:

$\dot{x}=1+x^{2}y-(1+A)x = 1 + Ax -(1+A) x = 1 + Ax -Ax -x = 0$, so

$1 - x = 0$, yielding $x = 1$.

So, we have a fixed point at $(1, A)$.

Yes, your method is correct.

If you wanted to analyze the behaviors, you would use this fixed point and see if it provides information on the behavior with the Jacobian evaluated at it (if these are not borderline points).

Here are the direction fields and phase portraits for $A = -1$, $A = 0$ and $A=1$.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Regards

Comment: Hi Amzoti. If you find the stability of different equi-points - if they are stable, as time tends to infinity, is it right to think the solution tends towards to stable point if the initial condition is close?

Comment: It depends on the type of stability, but generally, yes. If you have solutions that are positive or negative exponentials or trig functions, the behaviors are pretty clear. However, sometimes you have strange equations and there is a combination of these functions and it is not as clear. A small change in the IC can result in a very large swing. In the examples above, it is pretty clear regarding the global stability of initial points.

Comment: Could you recommend any reading to understand this better? I understand linearising non-linear systems, findings fixed points and stability, but I am not confident of the maths stating what happens as time tends to infinity and why it tends to the fixed point.

Comment: I really like the books: 1) Differential Equations: A Dynamical Systems Approach: Ordinary Differential Equations, 
John H. Hubbard, Beverly H. West and 2) Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos: With Applications to Physics, Biology ...
 By Steven H. Strogatz. There are also some nice ones online and other book recommendations too.

Comment: I appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: Here is an online book that is also a gentle introduction: http://www.ams.jhu.edu/~ers/invite/book.pdf

Comment: I think that's just the sort of explanation I needed; having a look through it now.

Comment: Hi Amzoti, I've had a go and said what I think. If it's okay, could you have a quick check? http://i.stack.imgur.com/7tWeu.png

Comment: Looks great! The point at $(0,0)$ is called a saddle point. The point $(1,0)$ is called a sink and is stable. Everything else is spot on. By the way, you might want to specify where the IC start to end up there as the other critical points change things. Regards

Comment: This is the bit I'm not so sure on - it is obvious in one dimensions, but with two dimensions, I am not so sure. I can see for $x<0$ it will tend to $-\infty$, for $x,y>0$, it tends to the sink, and for $x>0$, $y<0$ a mixture (the fixed point I ignored is obviously unstable). Is it enough to say if the IC is sufficiently close to the fixed point it will stay there as $t\rightarrow \infty$? http://i.stack.imgur.com/ySp8y.png

Comment: From the phase portrait, you can see that any IC to the right and some to the left of the CP will go to the FP. If you plot all the critical points, you can add lines to the x and y values of the regions and where they approach or are diverted away from the CP. For your example, any IC to the right will go the FP, so it can be very far away. Hope that is clear.

Comment: Yes, thank you and I appreciate the help today! Is there a mathematical way to know this without plotting the phase portrait?

Comment: By the way, Mathematica and other tools can draw multidimensional phase portraits. The eigenvalues are real, negative, equal, the solution form is of the form $e^{-t} ...$, so what happens as $t$ approaches infinity.

Comment: The solution tends to zero and as you're linearising around the fixed point, that shows it converges to the fixed point?

Comment: That is correct. I plot the phase portrait for the system you gave as it is defined in your problem. This shows the global behavior. The Jacobian tells us the behavior of that FP and its type. This is typically enough (see Strogantz for when not) to tell all you need. In the future, please post a new question as this is a lot of work and not the way the site is intended to be used. Regards

Comment: Thank you I think I understand it all now. And sorry, I only expected to ask one quick question! Regards

Comment: By the way, which tool are you using for the phase plot? It would be interesting to see a 3d version of the phase portrait.

Comment: DEplot in Maple. I think you can use DEplot3d as well, but I have not tried it.

Comment: It would be nice to compare the linearized to the actual 3D, so give it a go!